# Unable to put focus on a field after closing dialogbox

Tags: javascript, xpages

In my XPages application I am trying to set focus on a field that is a bootstrap date picker after a dialog box is closed:

```
XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dlgLMAValidDate}');
//I thought this would work but is does not
//$('#{id:inpLMAValid}').focus();
//alternative attempt:
//does not work either
var el = XSP.getElementById('#{id:inpLMAValid}');
var ef = dojo.byId(el);
ef.focus();
```

I wonder what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following works for me:

```
XSP.closeDialog('#{id:dlgLMAValidDate}');
var el = XSP.getElementById('#{id:inpLMAValid}');
el.focus();
el.scrollIntoView();
```

Comment: Thank you Patrick! I believe focus was already on but I was not navigated to the field. I was in the assumption this would occur automatically.